# ruby on rails 3 reload using cached data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using the activerecord reload command in my app seems to be using cached data when called.

I can replicate within the debugger by doing the following.

```
u = User.find(1)
u.first_name
#outputs bob

# manually change first_name for record 1 to jim with PGadmin or with rails console

u.reload
u.valid?
#outputs true
u.first_name
#outputs bob

#if i do this again
u = User.find(1)
#old data again
u.first_name
#outputs bob

#if i load data this way
u = User.where('id = 1').first
#new data
u.first_name 
#outputs jim
```

When looking at my log file after running reload it prints out

[1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1

So it seems to be using the cache

My environment: Rails 3.0.3, Ruby 1.8.7, Ubuntu 10.04, PostgreSQL 8.4

Comment: Please provide a more detailed example showing how you manually change the database row, and please provide the output of w.valid?.

Comment: Did you remember to save the record after changing the name?

Comment: Yes the record has been saved.  If i reload the page it picks up the change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do a write (e.g. by calling `save` on some model), so that the query cache gets blown up.

If you look at your development.log when you do `reload`, ActiveRecord does issue a SELECT query. However, it doesn't blow up the query cache, and it is used to answer the `User.find(1)` query.

I think that reload is meant for when you update the database from some other part of your application. I also think that you can wrap your find like this to avoid the cache:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
  User.find(1)
end
```

Comment: I had to use both uncached and reload

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your administrative tool really changed the data in DB. For example write the data by one tool and read this data by another tool.

Comment: added additional info to show that different query returns new data showing that data is saved