# self join association undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, jqgrid, associations

I have a model, Item, that comes in three types, implemented using Single Table Inheritance. Item has a tree hierarchy that is represented using a has_many :through relationship for both the parents (called groups) and the children (called sub_items). One of the subclasses (we'll call it ItemA) must have only one parent at all times (but the other subclasses can have 0 or more parents). I couldn't figure out how to implement validations that would enforce the rules of the tree hierarchy, so I left them out.

ItemA has a helper method, `parent`, to get its parent. Sometimes this method will raise `undefined method 'first' for nil:NilClass`. It doesn't always happen, but it does in certain situations.

### Situation 1

I am using jqGrid to list all the ItemAs. I use sorting functionality for some of the columns, including the parent. The grid would initially load the ItemAs successfully, showing that they all had parents as they should. However, when I tried to sort the parent column, I would get the error as if they suddenly disappeared. It went away when I removed `includes(:groups)` from the sorting method. I don't understand why that would help, but I figured the problem was solved. Until...

### Situation 2

I am testing my app with Rspec, Factory Girl, and Selenium. In one of my tests, I call the `parent` method on an instance of ItemA created using Factory Girl. It raises the error. My tests that use the `parent` method indirectly don't fail. For example, the `parent` method is called on the index page for ItemA, and many tests visit that page without problem. This situation has not been resolved. My app no longer has any calls to `includes`, so that isn't part of it this time.

### Relevant Code

**ItemA**

```
class ItemA < Item
  # This method is called in Situation 1
  def self.sort_by_parent sort_order
    all.sort_by(&:parent_name).tap do |i|
      i.reverse! if sort_order == :desc
    end
  end
  
  def parent
    groups.take
  end

  def parent_name
    parent.component_name
  end
end
```

**Item**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_groups, foreign_key: 'sub_item_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :item_groups
  has_many :group_items, class_name: 'ItemGroup', foreign_key: 'group_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sub_items, through: :group_items
end
```

**update_spec**

```
feature 'ItemA editing', js: true do
  given!(:item_a) { create(:item_a) }
  given!(:parent) { create(:item_b) }

  scenario 'when parent', focus: true do
    itemas_page = ItemAsPage.visit # This is a custom page object

    # Situation 2 occurs here
    itemas_page.edit_parent item_a.parent_name, parent.component_name

    expect(itemas_page).to have_item_a_with parent.component_name
  end
end
```

**Why is the `parent` method sometimes reading as nil, and how do I get it to always produce a value?**

EDIT: As I'm changing my code, I'm coming across more situations that cause this error. I checked the source. Here's a snapshot of `ActiveRecord::FinderMethods`:

```
module ActiveRecord::FinderMethods
  def take(limit = nil)
    limit ? limit(limit).to_a : find_take
  end

  private
  def find_take
    if loaded?
      @records.first
    else
      @take ||= limit(1).to_a.first
    end
  end
end
```

For debugging purposes, I modified the `parent` method to look like this:

```
def parent
  groups.tap {|g| puts '@records: ' + g.instance_variable_get(:@records).inspect }.take
end
```

`@records` is nil. I tried changing it to `groups.reload.take` to get `@records` to load, but it's not working. I'm using `groups.limit(1).to_a.first` right now, which is working, but I'm curious to find out what sort of bug in my app is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that despite calling reload, Rails still uses the cached version of the query. The same problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384517/ruby-on-rails-3-reload-using-cached-data). This fixes it:

```
class ItemA < Item
  def parent
    ActiveRecord::Base.uncached { groups.take }
  end
end
```